# C# hex to string problems

Tags: c#, string

i making a program with CSharp Language.
But, I have a big problem.
I'm making a program that reading a file by a hex and converting hex to string.
but, i can't get string perfectly.
The blue one is a hex code that i want to converting to string.
[this is hex code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt79r.png)

but i cant get only 59fd50a62fb9a8ef, not including a file extension.

i want to get perfect string like 59fd50a62f9a8ef.bmp

How can i do ?

This is a source code that converting a hex to string.

```
    string toString(string hexString)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
        }
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

Comment: Why exactlay are you trying to do this?

Comment: because i need to get exacted file name in database files.

Comment: There is no file extension for the hex you show, so just append it to your converted string.

Comment: Thank you're answer but,  BM6 is not bmp extension?..

Comment: please put the code that you are reading the file from, the extension is for the the file, not for the content of the file

Comment: You don't read by hex codes. You see them with hex codes. You read them by bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the file extension from the bytes you highlighted. As far as I can tell they contain a hexadecimal filename, which you have extracted successfully already, an end of string character (two zeroes), the start of a bitmap (`BM`) and the length of the bitmap (`36 10 00 00` in [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little-endian)). So, to get a filename you just have to append `.bmp` to your hexadecimal string.

If, however, the image is not always a bitmap, then you should create a function that deduces the filetype from the bytes after the end of string character.